# CSS Font displaying different in IE7 and IE8?

Tags: css

```
#solutionsNav div.leadgen div 
{
    position: relative;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 9pt;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

In IE8  the font looks bolder than in IE7 I was just wondering why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly this ?
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/02/03/524367.aspx

Comment: Another thing you can try to see if it's a ClearType issue is to set the font-weight to bold and see if the bold text is more bold in IE8 as well.